# Upgrading from a smaller hard drive to a larger one on a dual boot system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

So I have Ubuntu and Windows 7 on a 500GB hard drive setup for dual boot. Recently some of the sectors on the Windows 7 partition of the drive went bad. I want to upgrade the hard drive I have now to a 2TB one and also get rid of the sector issue at the same time.

What would be the best (and safest) way to go about transferring the whole system to a new, larger hard drive?

Comment: How to move Windows to a different partition is off topic on Ask Ubuntu but welcome over on [SU].

Comment: @david --  he is asking how to move ubuntu

Comment: @ravery: "What would be the best (and safest) way to go about transferring the whole system to a new, larger hard drive?" – To me that sounds like it refers to *all* operating system installations on that machine which is Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: @david -- and since ubuntu is included it belongs here. thou you are right about it being a dulplicate question

Answer (score -1):

clonezilla is an excellent software for duplicating drives.

get a bootable image here http://clonezilla.org

burn the image to disk. and boot it.
it supports all file systems